# Single sign in authentication with disqus via google/facebook tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth, disqus

I have a website which supports authentication via Google and Facebook(using [passport](http://passportjs.org/)  which uses the `OAuth 2.0 API`). I am also using [disqus](https://disqus.com/home/explore/) which helps me manage the comments system on my web site.

My problem is that a user which is already signed-in via Google/Facebook needs to make an extra sign-in with/to disqus in order to comment.

Is there a way to pass the Facebook/Google tokens to disqus and manage just a single authentication?

I tried to look a lot on google and particularly on disqus documentation but didn't found something useful for **google and facebook** just found this [link](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-single-sign-on#configure-domain) which didn't help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: I was struggling with this myself, hopefully you'll find some kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be possible for security reasons. Disqus and You are different people/identities. Disqus has their own app and you have your own. The tokens generated for your application is only meant for your own app. If it can be shared with other applications (Disqus in this context), then other apps would be able to take actions (say post some contents) using your app.

Comment: Do you have any sources which supporting it ? Thanks!

Comment: @GroundIns I answered from my personal experience of implementing oAuth servers.